# How to make a difference between messages I sent and others I received when reading messages

Tags: mesibo

I use read message API to get all messages for one conversation between two users.
The result is the following (check image). [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2bO7.png)

How I am supposed to know what are the messages I have sent and others I received?

The purpose is to display the conversation like in the picture.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYVM5.png)

This is how I read messages sent between two users.

```
function readConversationWithUser(userId){
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    var messageSession = api.readDbSession(userId.toString(), 0, null,
    function on_read(count) {
      var messages = messageSession.getMessages();
      resolve(messages);
    });

    messageSession.enableReadReceipt(true);
    messageSession.read(100);
  });
}
```

userId is my user's unique address.

Thank you very much for your help!

PS: Is there any library to use with angular application or typescript?

Comment: Hi, you can check the m.status or m.incoming() to know if the message is incoming or outgoing. m.status will give you additional info.

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer, 
I checked what you told me and finally could resolve the issue with: msg.isIncoming() 
the status returns a number like 19, 1, 0... So it is not clear what this status means, and can not find anything about it in doc.

Comment: Open api.js in an editor and search for MESIBO_MSGSTATUS_OUTBOX. You will find an entire list of status. Also refer to here https://mesibo.com/documentation/api/real-time-api/data-structures/